# Complexity of mapping identity function to a Scala collection?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-compiler

When I apply the Scala predefined `identity` function to a collection using the `map` method the original collection is returned unchanged.  However, is the compiler smart enough to simply return the unchanged collection as an `O(1)` operation? Or will the identity function still be applied to each element in the original collection yielding a `O(n)` operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward to check that this is not the case. Start by making a test file with possibly optimized forms and compile it using `scalac` (with or without `-optimise`)

```
/// TestMap.scala
object TestMap {
  def mapOption[T](o: Option[T]): Option[T] = o.map(identity)
  def mapList[T](l: List[T]): List[T] = l.map(identity)
  def mapSeq[T](l: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = l.map(identity)
}
```

Then, checking `javap -c TestMap.class` you can see that nothing got optimized past specializing `map` to `mapSeq`, `mapList`, or `mapOption`:

```
Compiled from "TestMap.scala"
public final class TestMap {
  public static <T extends java/lang/Object> scala.collection.Seq<T> mapSeq(scala.collection.Seq<T>);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #16                 // Field TestMap$.MODULE$:LTestMap$;
       3: aload_0       
       4: invokevirtual #18                 // Method TestMap$.mapSeq:(Lscala/collection/Seq;)Lscala/collection/Seq;
       7: areturn       

  public static <T extends java/lang/Object> scala.collection.immutable.List<T> mapList(scala.collection.immutable.List<T>);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #16                 // Field TestMap$.MODULE$:LTestMap$;
       3: aload_0       
       4: invokevirtual #22                 // Method TestMap$.mapList:(Lscala/collection/immutable/List;)Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
       7: areturn       

  public static <T extends java/lang/Object> scala.Option<T> mapOption(scala.Option<T>);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #16                 // Field TestMap$.MODULE$:LTestMap$;
       3: aload_0       
       4: invokevirtual #26                 // Method TestMap$.mapOption:(Lscala/Option;)Lscala/Option;
       7: areturn
```

More simply, this sort of optimization just doesn't extend well in languages with side-effects (on the other hand, in Haskell, this sort of thing happens regularly). Should the compiler optimise `l.map(x => { println(x); x })` to `l` or not for example?

Comment: So, the identity function does get applied to each element of collection?

Comment: Yes, although I just realized my javap output isn't sufficient here. Updating that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Rex Kerr's [handy Thyme utility](https://github.com/Ichoran/thyme) confirms Alec's findings.  The `identity` runtime is roughly proportional to the collection size.

```
val smallC = Vector.tabulate(90)(_*2)
val bigC = Vector.tabulate(900)(_*2)

val th = ichi.bench.Thyme.warmed(verbose = print)
th.pbenchOffWarm("A vs. B")(th.Warm(smallC.map(identity)))(th.Warm(bigC.map(identity)))
```

---

```
Benchmark comparison (in 4.694 s): A vs. B
Significantly different (p ~= 0)
  Time ratio:    9.31267   95% CI 9.25599 - 9.36935   (n=20)
    First     1.492 us   95% CI 1.487 us - 1.496 us
    Second    13.89 us   95% CI 13.82 us - 13.96 us
```

Answer (score 2):

> When I apply the Scala predefined `identity` function to a collection using the `map` method the original collection is returned unchanged.

No, it isn't. A *new* collection with identical contents is returned. Constructing this new collection will typically be O(n).

> However, is the compiler smart enough to simply return the unchanged collection as an `O(1)` operation? Or will the identity function still be applied to each element in the original collection yielding a `O(n)` operation?

In order to perform such an optimization, the compiler will have to decide that the function to be applied is extensionally equal to the identity function. This problem is called the *Function Problem* and is known to be undecidable. (It can be proven using the Halting Problem, for example.)

Of course, it *would* be possible to optimize for the specific function `Predef.identity`, not just any identity function. But the Scala compiler designers are not fond of such one-off special-case optimizations, that only help standard library code. They prefer general optimizations that benefits *all* code.

Comment: Well, technically, the question only asks about doing this for `Predef.identity`, not for all functions extensionally equal to it, and this could be done quite simply. But slowing down very slightly all `map` operations to speed up a very rare case isn't worthwhile.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I added a final paragraph with a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring execution time seems to indicate that identity function is O(n):

Function for measuring code execution time, from [this link](http://biercoff.com/easily-measuring-code-execution-time-in-scala/):

```
def time[R](block: => R): R = {  
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
    result
}

time {(1 to 100000000).map(identity)}  // Elapsed time: 8893077396ns

time {(1 to 10).map(identity)} // Elapsed time: 341129ns

// while only creation of range takes similar order of magnitude times. 

time {(1 to 10)}  // Elapsed time: 30250ns

time {(1 to 100000000)} // Elapsed time: 32351ns
```